# Expected Value of Infinite Geometric Sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find the sum of the following sequence: $\frac{7}{10} *\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{n*(3/10)^n}$.

The original question is:
You have a 30% chance to gain an extra "reroll" after every reroll. What is the expected number of reroll's after one reroll? For context, this is from the game TFT and is the augment "Golden Ticket".

I'm interpreting this as

$\frac{7}{10} *\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{n*(3/10)^n}$.

I'm taking the derivative of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(3/10)^n}$ because that is just $\frac{A_1}{1-r}.$ This gives us $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{n*(3/10)^{n-1}}$. and then multiplying by 3/10 and also 7/10 to get to my original equation.

However my answer is 9/70 which makes no sense because the odds of getting only one free roll is 21/100.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your equation seems incorrect. The number of rolls is always one more than the number of rerolls. So it should be $(n+1)$ in the summation of GP, not $(n)$, where n goes from $0$ to infinity.

The correct answer is $\textbf{$\frac{10}7$}$. Let's solve it using your method of GP and using an intuitive faster method as well.

> Method $1$: Geometric Progression

$E = \frac{7}{10}\cdot1 + \frac{3}{10}\cdot\frac{7}{10}\cdot2 + (\frac{3}{10})^2\cdot\frac{7}{10}\cdot3  +...$

$=> E = \frac{7}{10} \cdot \left( 1 + \frac{3}{10}\cdot2 + (\frac{3}{10})^2\cdot3  +... \right)$

$=> E = \frac7{10} \cdot \left( \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(n+1)\cdot (\frac3{10})^n} \right)$

$=> E = \frac7{10} \cdot \left( \frac{100}{49} \right)$ [You can look at the
calculations for this step [here](https://www.emathhelp.net/en/calculators/calculus-2/series-calculator/?f=%28r%2B1%29*%283%2F10%29%5Er&var=r&a=0&b=inf) ]

$=> E = \frac{10}{7}$

> Method $2$: Recursion

Note that we can define the entire EV recursively as follows:

$$E = \frac{7}{10} \cdot 1 + \frac{3}{10} \cdot (1 + E)$$
$$=> E = \frac{10}{7}$$